# Generic Parameter in Powershell

Tags: powershell, generics, pipeline

In powershell, is there a way to specify that a parameter is generic? Basically, the function I'm writing doesn't care what type you hand it, as it technically works with all objects, but if I specify `[object[]]` as the parameter type, the objects loose type information which may or may not be handled correctly by other CmdLets down the pipeline.

```
function Pack-Objects{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [object[]]$InputObjects
    )

    BEGIN{
        $OutputObjects = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
    }PROCESS{
        $OutputObjects.Add($_) | Out-Null
    }END{
        Write-Verbose "Passing off $($OutputObjects.Count) objects downstream" 
        return ,$OutputObjects.ToArray()
    }
}
```

For example, if I run `1,2,3 | Pack-Objects | Get-Member`, the returned type is `System.Object[]`. I want it so that if I pass it integers, it gives me an array of integers; string and array of strings; and so on.

Comment: I don't understand how you are losing type information.  Yes, your return type is System.Object[], but the individual objects inside retain their type information (in your case, System.Int32).  Other than boxing concerns, what's the worry?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need it but this should do what you want:

```
 [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        $InputObjects
    )    
        BEGIN{
                $script:i = 0
                $script:OutputObjects = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
              }        
        PROCESS{
                foreach ( $_ in $InputObjects)
                { 
                  $script:t = $_.gettype() | select -expa name
                  if ( $i -gt 0 )
                  {
                     if ( $ts -notmatch $t ){"types are differents!!";break}
                  }

                $ts = $t
                $i++
                $OutputObjects.Add($_) | Out-Null
                }
               }        
       END{
            iex "[$t[]]`$OutputObjects = `$OutputObjects.toarray()"                    
            @(,$OutputObjects)
           }


PS C:\ps> ("q","d","e" | .\Pack-Objects.ps1).gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String[]                                 System.Array    

PS C:\ps> (1,2,3 | .\Pack-Objects.ps1).gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32[]                                  System.Array

PS C:\ps> 1,2,3,"e" | .\Pack-Objects.ps1 
types are differents!!
```